# checkbox validation is not working as expected

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to validate the form when user click the submit button using bootstrap and angularjs.If any of the field in the form is blank i want to dislay the error message below the blank elements.

Demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/55lFImusbCznYjLXypDu?p=preview

html code:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
   <div>Select Color : </div>
      <label name="team" ng-repeat="color in colorNames" class="checkbox-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="{{color}}" ng-checked="selectedColor.indexOf(color) > -1" ng-click="userSelection(color)"> {{color}}
                  <br>  </label><br>
                <div ng-show="myForm.$submitted || myForm.color.$touched">
                    <p class="error-mesg" ng-show="headerForm.color.$error.required">Select the color</p>
                </div>
            <div class="">
                <div style="color: black;">Username : </div>
               <input type="text" name="user" value="" required>
                <div ng-show="myForm.$submitted || myForm.user.$touched">
                    <p class="error-mesg" ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">The Username is required</p>
                </div>
            </div>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submitForm(myForm)">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

My above code is failing to show error message below the checkboxes when not selected.I want to show an error message "Please Select the color" below the checkboxes when user click on submit button without selecting atleast one checkbox.And when user click on any of the check box the error message should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You can add dynamically required for checkbox input: `ng-required="selectedColor.length === 0"`

if you do not select color, checkboxs will be required, when color is selected, then is it unrequired.

```
<input ng-required="selectedColor.length === 0" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please select the color')" type="checkbox" name="color" value="{{color}}" ng-checked="selectedColor.indexOf(color) > -1" ng-click="userSelection(color)">
```

Comment: ng-model="user" is also missing on user input.

Comment: I want to show the error message i have given  'Please select the color' below the checkboxes. With the code you suggested https://plnkr.co/edit/qteeuHzdfCeOufRTZI83?p=preview it is showing 'Please check this box if you want to proceed' by pointing to first checkbox.

Comment: @dexter: actually you don't use ng-model on your 2 inputs fields, $scope.myForm.$valid is always true.

Comment: <input oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Put  here custom message')"> You can change text using oninvalid attribute (html5).  He can use ngChecked directive instead of ngModel.

Comment: @JonathanAnctil - I have add ng-model but still it is not reconizing my custom error message 'Please select the color' . Updated link https://plnkr.co/edit/xRJiBjh4mQqr0lpPn15x?p=preview

Comment: Check my answer, i update it with ``oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Put here custom message')"``

Comment: I'm Sorry but nothing seems to work for me.. Can anyone modify the code in link here https://plnkr.co/edit/nlmQ7OM09QpprGPGWPMy?p=preview . I tried but failed to show the messages i have given in <p class="error-mesg"..>

Comment: @MatejMarconak - I'm seeing the error message even after selecting the checkbox https://plnkr.co/edit/X93fx6vR0iWXNUrBmXM3?p=preview . To reproduce the error first click on submit button without selecting the checkbox, it prompts to pLease slect the color'. After selecting the color also when clicked on submit it is showing the error message.